# Looking for the opposite of Schadenfreude

Tags: single-word-request

If it is possible to be happy because of others suffering (Schadenfreude) is there a word for the opposite? To be happy at the success of others? "Segenfreude" seems possible, but I wonder if there is a more colloquial term expressing the same thing.

Comment: "opposite of Schadenfreude" :
My first thinking was "Mitgefühl", but then I read the complete question... If you want an action/reaction "gratulieren" could be something...

Comment: I would also have suggested *Mitgefühl* but it is mostly restricted to memorial cards these days. *Empathie* (engl. *empathy*) would not convey the success component and sounds too technical in many contexts. So possibly there is no single word counterpiece.

Comment: Not a more colloquial term, but a closer antonym might be *Mitfreude*. It's rare according to both [Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Mitfreude) and [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Mitfreude) though.

Comment: "Gratulieren" seems more immediate to me... "Schadenfreude" (at least in my mind) can be applied over a much longer term (e.g. the joy at the slow steady decline of a childhood bully). Is my understanding of the immediacy of both terms accurate?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is expressed with the term

> sich für jemanden freuen

like in

> Als mein Kollege befördert wurde, habe ich mich sehr für ihn gefreut

Comment: es heißt sich für jemande**n** freuen :)

Comment: @messerbill natürlich, danke

Comment: "sich für jemanden freuen" is familiar. I wondered if there was a single word, which it looks like there isn't. Mitgefühl seems more like empathy, a sharing in the same emotion, and yes, reads like a memorial card.

Comment: *Mitgefühl* **is** actually empathy - And doesn't really denote "be happy with someone" (maybe, in rare cases), but rather only with "be sad with someone".

Answer (score 1):

You could use the expression

> Jemandem etwas **gönnen**
>
> Ich **gönne** dir deinen Erfolg sehr!

The noun for this verb is **Gunst**.

> Ich stehe in ihrer Gunst

And the opposite is **Missgunst**. This is more or less the same thing like **Neid** but imho it comes very close to **Schadenfreude** as well.

Comment: interesting hints: I would use "stehe in Gunst von xy" that this person is "wohlwollend meinem Tun" / "mir wohlgesinnt" which I would translate more to "I get support of xy", not just "xy is happy about my doing". I see this difference as Missgunst is for me "activly hated about any success" rather only "contextual happy about so. else failure" as in Schadenfreude. So I would also say "ich gönne Dir das" as opposite of "schadenfreude", just not "Du stehst in meiner Gunst".

Answer (score 1):

Not really exising (at least to my knowledge), but an acceptable word for the opposite of Schadenfreude would be

> Mitfreude

It supposes that the primary protagonist feels joy about whatever (say: success), and the secondary protagonist shares this feeling although not having been part of the initial action.