# Is there an antonym for Schadenfreude?

Tags: antonym

**Question**

If Schadenfreude means *joy at someone else's failure or ill-fortune*, is there an antonym that means *resentment at someone else's success or good fortune*?

---

**Note**

This is a different kind of opposite to the one mentioned in this previous question [Looking for the opposite of Schadenfreude](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/53131/looking-for-the-opposite-of-schadenfreude)

Comment: "resentment at someone else's success or good fortune?" We call that envy, "Neid" in German.

Comment: Wouldn't the opposite rather be something like *empathy*?

Comment: @Polygnome if it's an antonym in regard to the "joy"/"Freude" part of *Schadenfreude*, then yes. Or maybe even better: compassion/ *Mitleid*.

Comment: According to The Simpsons, the answer is "sour grapes" ;-)
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B01e7n4RzZc

Comment: Purely via googletranslate: replaced "malicious joy" with "benificant sadness" to get "wohltätige Traurigkeit".  As they say,  Don't Try This At Home.

Comment: Schadenleiden :v

Answer (score 59):

Not really an answer to this particular question, but for completeness here's the four possible logical variations of this:

```
                  ┃ You're happy about it   │  You're unhappy about it
━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━╋━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┿━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━
Someone's lucky   ┃  Gunst,                 │  Neid / Missgunst
                  ┃“Ich freue mich für dich”│
──────────────────╂─────────────────────────┼───────────────────────
Someone's unlucky ┃  Schadenfreude          │  Mitleid
```

Comment: This is unexpectedly useful!

Comment: @gented it certainly is unexpectedly popular! Hoffentlich wird keiner neidisch, sondern gönnt mir die Upvotes. Ich habe Mitleid mit den anderen Antworten, keineswegs Schadenfreude dass sie weniger beliebt sind...

Answer (score 26):

*Missgunst* (translates somewhat literally into "failing to grant/allow something to someone") is probably what your looking for.

Comment: To me the concepts seem quite close to each other, both negative.

Answer (score 23):

The antonym searched (so instead of joy over ones sorrow becomes sorrow over ones joy) seems the quite simple word (present in many languages):

> Neid (envy, jealousy).

Comment: Couldn't "Eifersucht" also be used for jealousy, or does that have a different connotation?

Comment: *Eifersucht* is mostly used for relationships, where one person receives or is assumed to receive affection by an outsider, so its not a simple synonym.

Comment: OK, that makes sense. Thanks

Answer (score 8):

From yesterday, hardly used today:

> Scheelsucht

Comment: Do you know as a "native speaker knows", that the term "from yesterday" refers to something oldfashioned in language? I found as first glance this: https://dict.leo.org/forum/viewUnsolvedquery.php?idThread=650668&idForum=1&lang=de&lp=ende

Comment: @ShegitBrahm: Since I'm one of the natives, yes, I do.

Comment: thanks, again what learned. My knowledge is small and I did not know that.

Comment: good one! not often used today and also regional from my area, the rhineland - https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/scheel#:~:text=%5B1%5D%20schief%2C%20schiefblickend,sch%C4%93l%20%E2%80%9Eschief(%C3%A4ugig)%E2%80%9C

Answer (score 3):

I think the first question is, what's the real antonym. As a german speaker, I would see the antonym for Schadenfreude to be a word, that conveys "being happy that you're happy" (as antonym to "being happy that you're unhappy").

There is probably a word for this, maybe someone can comment or edit the answer.

As a phrase one would say "Ich freue mich für dich" / "Ich freue mich mit dir".

---

Another way to look at it (which does not feel like being the antonym to Schadenfreude in german) would be "I am unhappy that you're unhappy" and this would be "Mitleid".

Answer (score 2):

"Es sei dir gegönnt"
bzw.
jemanden etwas gönnen

Comment: Welcome to German.SE. It is common sense to answer an english written question in english. Additionally it is a bit short - which can happen - and so maybe: is there an (online) resource that can be used to understand the term you write.

Comment: @ShegitBrahm: Gefragt ist ein deutscher Ausdruck - Du mokierst Dich ernsthaft über das "bzw." zwischen den beiden?